# why do we use JS function expression in some cases say rather than an inline function?

Tags: javascript

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value > 10;
}

const filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

the above example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#filtering_out_all_small_values) would there have been any disadvantages? if we rewrite code as `const filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(x=>(x>10));`  resulting in same output .a function expression way (ensures of course code would be more readable and hoisting not done).

Comment: Biggest disadvantage is you (a) can't test the function in isolation, and (b) can't use the function anywhere else. Whether or not that's an **actual** disadvantage depends on context.

Comment: Presumably a typo, but you have `>` vs `>=` in your two examples. In terms of inline arrow function vs named function, the main difference is the named function is reusable in other filters.